# Cordova- Push notification firebase not coming in status bar but Working in android

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova, firebase, apple-push-notifications

I m adding firebase to my cordova project. I have problem with push notification, The notification is printed into the console when it is running. but not coming to notification bar..

Any idea about this.. **do i need to add any other delegate methods..**

> I m getting log -> FCM connected and when app enters background log ->
>   FCM Disconnected

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication*)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions
{
    CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:screenBounds];
    self.window.autoresizesSubviews = YES;

    // only set if not already set in subclass
    if (self.viewController == nil) {
        self.viewController = [[CDVViewController alloc] init];
    }

    // Set your app's start page by setting the <content src='foo.html' /> tag in config.xml.
    // If necessary, uncomment the line below to override it.
    // self.viewController.startPage = @"index.html";

    // NOTE: To customize the view's frame size (which defaults to full screen), override
    // [self.viewController viewWillAppear:] in your view controller.

    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];




    // [self saveDeviceTokenAPI:@"83a86eb457edd131a2ace741e1214d988482dd3618f8858e1dba736e1900c733"];

    if  ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications)])
    {
        NSLog(@"My token is......: ");

        // iOS 8 Notifications
        [application registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];

        [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"My token is: ");

        // iOS < 8 Notifications
        [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
         (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];
    }




    return YES;
}

#pragma  mark :-  Push Starts here


#pragma mark- Push Notification Delegate Methods

- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken
{
    NSLog(@"My token is: %@", deviceToken);

    NSString * deviceTokenString = [[[[deviceToken description]
                                      stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"<" withString: @""]
                                     stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @">" withString: @""]
                                    stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @" " withString: @""];

    NSLog(@"the generated device token string is : %@",deviceTokenString);

  //  [self saveDeviceTokenAPI:deviceTokenString];

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:deviceTokenString forKey:@"deviceToken"];

    NSLog(@"the generated device token from User defaluts : %@",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"deviceToken"]);

}

- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError*)error
{
    NSLog(@"Failed to get token, error: %@", error);
}


#pragma  mark  for Push End here


// this happens while we are running ( in the background, or from within our own app )
// only valid if 40x-Info.plist specifies a protocol to handle
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication*)application openURL:(NSURL*)url sourceApplication:(NSString*)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
{
    if (!url) {
        return NO;
    }

    // all plugins will get the notification, and their handlers will be called
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotification:[NSNotification notificationWithName:CDVPluginHandleOpenURLNotification object:url]];

    return YES;
}

#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED < 90000
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication*)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow*)window
#else
- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)application:(UIApplication*)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow*)window
#endif
{
    // iPhone doesn't support upside down by default, while the iPad does.  Override to allow all orientations always, and let the root view controller decide what's allowed (the supported orientations mask gets intersected).
    NSUInteger supportedInterfaceOrientations = (1 << UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) | (1 << UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) | (1 << UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) | (1 << UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);

    return supportedInterfaceOrientations;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this function:

```
- (void)launchRemoteNotificationInForegroundWithUserInfo:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
    UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    notification.fireDate = [NSDate date];
    notification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
    notification.repeatInterval = 0;
    notification.alertTitle = userInfo[@"aps"][@"alert"][@"body"];
    notification.alertBody = userInfo[@"aps"][@"alert"][@"title"];
    notification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
    notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:notification];

    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                              initWithTitle:userInfo[@"aps"][@"alert"][@"title"]
                              message:userInfo[@"aps"][@"alert"][@"body"]
                              delegate:self
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                              otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [alertView show];
}
```

and call it in

```
didReceiveRemoteNotification:
```